# How to partially transpose a CSV table in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in a csv file with weekly sales data by store by product across many weeks and trying to partially transpose the data so that each row represents a weekly transaction by product, store, week

Going From This:

```
Product,Store,9/1/18,9/8/18,9/15/18,9/22/18
vacuum,123,1,5,3,3
toaster,456,5,7,4,10
```

To This:

```
Product,Store,Week,Sales
vacuum,123,9/1/18,1
vacuum,123,9/8/18,5
vacuum,123,9/15/18,3
vacuum,123,9/22/18,3
toaster,456,9/1/18,5
toaster,456,9/8/18,7
toaster,456,9/15/18,4
toaster,456,9/22/18,10...
```

I'm brand new to Python (2 days old) and I semi-understand a full transpose using zip_longest/reader/writer, but cannot figure out how to do a partial version

Comment: The `0` following `123` looks out of place...

Comment: Thanks rahlf23.  Fixed that

Comment: I'm just reviewing first questions and don't know python but perhaps you can explain what you mean by a partial transpose, do you only want items? Or do you only want limit the number of rows? It feels like that extra bit of info may help someone better help you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also,

```
df.set_index(['Product','Store']).stack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Product  Store  level_2   0
0   vacuum    123   9/1/18   1
1   vacuum    123   9/8/18   5
2   vacuum    123  9/15/18   3
3   vacuum    123  9/22/18   3
4  toaster    456   9/1/18   5
5  toaster    456   9/8/18   7
6  toaster    456  9/15/18   4
7  toaster    456  9/22/18  10
```

With cleaned up column naming,

```
(df.set_index(['Product','Store'])
   .rename_axis('Week', axis=1)
   .stack()
   .rename('Sales')
   .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   Product  Store     Week  Sales
0   vacuum    123   9/1/18      1
1   vacuum    123   9/8/18      5
2   vacuum    123  9/15/18      3
3   vacuum    123  9/22/18      3
4  toaster    456   9/1/18      5
5  toaster    456   9/8/18      7
6  toaster    456  9/15/18      4
7  toaster    456  9/22/18     10
```

Comment: amazing answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use melt to do this:

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Product', 'Store',],
                       value_vars=['9/1/18', '9/8/18','9/15/18','9/22/18'], 
                       var_name='week', value_name='Sales')

    Product Store   week    Sales
0   vacuum  123  9/1/18     1
1   toaster 456  9/1/18     5
2   vacuum  123  9/8/18     5
3   toaster 456  9/8/18     7
4   vacuum  123  9/15/18    3
5   toaster 456  9/15/18    4
6   vacuum  123  9/22/18    3
7   toaster 456  9/22/18    10
```

Comment: I have a suggestion, `df.melt(id_vars=['Product', 'Store'], value_vars=df.columns[-4:], var_name='week', value_name='Sales')`

Comment: @Yuca Great improvement not to type in the column names

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.pivot()`:

```
df.pivot(index='Product', columns='Store').stack(level=[1,0]).reset_index()
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df = df.pivot(index='Product', columns='Store').stack(level=[1,0]).reset_index()

df.columns = ['Product','Store','Week','Sales']
```

Which gives:

```
   Product  Store     Week  Sales
0  toaster    456   9/1/18    5.0
1  toaster    456   9/8/18    7.0
2  toaster    456  9/15/18    4.0
3  toaster    456  9/22/18   10.0
4   vacuum    123   9/1/18    1.0
5   vacuum    123   9/8/18    5.0
6   vacuum    123  9/15/18    3.0
7   vacuum    123  9/22/18    3.0
```

Comment: You can replace `.stack().stack()` with `stack(level=[1,0])` using `level` parameter for selecting levels in a multiindex header.  And, add a "Waahkaa" (Bruce Lee) sound at the end.

Comment: I knew there was a way to avoid `stack()` twice. Passed the list but was missing the `level` keyword. Much appreciated, edited my answer.